# Populate combos in Django and initialize them with a foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to populate two combos in a ModelForm, and I would like to initialize them with the current value of each foreign key.

My models are:

```
class Alumno(models.Model):
    idalumno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    padre_idpadre = models.ForeignKey('Padre', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='padre_idpadre', blank=True, null=True)
    curso_idcurso = models.ForeignKey('Curso', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='curso_idcurso')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'alumno'

class Curso(models.Model):
    idcurso = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    nombrecurso = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'curso'

class Padre(models.Model):
    idpadre = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    socio = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    primerapellido = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    segundoapellido = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'padre'
```

This is my Form in forms.py:

```
class AlumnoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    padre = PadreModelChoiceField(queryset=Padre.objects.all(), initial=**XXXXXXXXX**) #I would like to init here with the value of the FK
    curso = CursoModelChoiceField(queryset=Curso.objects.all(), initial=**XXXXXXXXXX**) #And here too
    class Meta:
        model = Alumno

        fields = ('nombre','padre','curso',)
        labels = {
            'nombre': 'Nombre',
            'padre': 'Padre',
            'curso': 'Curso',
        }
```

In views.py

```
def alumno_editar(request, pk):
    alumno = get_object_or_404(Alumno, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AlumnoForm(request.POST, instance=alumno)
        if form.is_valid():
            alumno = form.save(commit=False) 
            alumno.save()

            return redirect('alumno_listar')
    else:
        form = AlumnoForm(instance=alumno)

    return render(request, 'administration/alumno_editar.html', {'form': form})
```

What should I write in the part XXXXXXXXXX of the code.
It could be misconception but I'm think is a common operation, althought I don't find it.

Comment: You don't do this at all. You pass an instance argument when you create the form in your view, which takes care of populating the fields with the correct values.

Comment: form = AlumnoForm(instance=alumno) I pass from view an instance of alumno, but I don't know how to access it from AlumnoForm. (I have completed the initial question with views.py)

Comment: You don't need to, that is everything you need to do. You don't even need to define `padre` and `curso` fields in your form.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman, I understand now!